# how to determine the size of an AUSampler instance?

Tags: ios, core-audio

How can I tell how much memory is being used by an instance for AUSampler (including, presumably, the soundFont data size).

I tried a simple `sizeof` (below) but that doesn't give me anything I understand. 4? 4 what?

**Context for this:** I'm creating a musical toy for iOS. `AUSampler` is monophonic, so two tracks using the same sampler instance cut each others' notes off. Also soundFonts may have many presets so if I want to use different presets of the same soundFont, I'll need to create multiple `AUSampler` instances. Since soundFonts can run to several megabytes or more, I want to determine what my memory overhead will be. - Thanks!

node: 4.000000 unit: 4.000000

```
Float64 nodeSize = sizeof(samplerNode);
Float64 unitSize = sizeof(samplerUnit);

printf("node: %f unit: %f \n", nodeSize, unitSize);
```

Comment: `sizeof` always returns size in bytes, so that's 4 bytes. And it's 4 because your samplerNode and samplerUnit are typedef'd pointers to some opaque structure, and pointers are 4 bytes long in iOS. In any case, `sizeof` can't possibly work, because it's evaluated at compile time, not run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Instruments from Xcode to report the memory usage of your app, and then try running your app with different numbers of instruments to get data to calculate the memory usage of each additional one.

The amount of memory used by any object, such as an AUSampler, can be very different from the size of an object (which is much larger than the size of an object pointer).

Comment: ok - thanks. I was hoping there was a more direct way. Working with Core Audio is often like an info scavenger hunt... (and not in a good way)